# Eclipse "Run as" does not show "Run as TestNg" option with TestNg installed & all relevant jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, selenium

I have **Windows 8.1 64 Bit** in my laptop and I have installed **Eclipse Mars** `R-win32-X86-64` and `jdk-8u71-windowsX64`.

Now when I am trying to run simple selenium code ,"Run as" does not show a "Run as TestNg" option. I have already added **TestNg**  and all relevant jar files in my code.
What can I do to fix this?

My code is below:

```
package newpkg;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.Random;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class Google {


    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    String baseurl = "https://www.google.co.in/";

    @BeforeTest
    public void initial() {

        driver.get(baseurl);

    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gs_htif0']")).sendKeys("Facebook");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sblsbb']")).click();

    }
}
```

I have added TestNG plugin but on running it is showing following errors:

> -Unknown option: -serport Usage: [-d output-directory] default output directory to : test-output [-testclass list of .class files or list of class names] [-sourcedir a source directory] [-annotations javadoc or JDK] Specifies the default annotation type to be used in suites when none is explicitly specified. This version of TestNG (15) supports both "javadoc" and "JDK" annotation types. [-groups comma-separated list of group names to be run] works only with -testclass

**Edit:**
I have installed from [this link](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/install-testng) and now Run as > Run as TestNG option is shown. But with error in console which I have posted above and Firefox driver cannot be launched.

**Edit2:**
No longer getting the above errors, but am now getting:

> eclipse.buildId=4.5.0.I20150603-2000 java.version=1.8.0_71 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments: -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product Command-line arguments: -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ui Warning Sat Feb 20 00:32:02 PST 2016 The notification timed out Version: 1.0.0.v20150617-0732 org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ui.l10n.Logs$LogTraceException at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ui.l10n.Logs$LogTraceException

Comment: share what you've tried http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ bibi .. please se my code below ,, i have also added TestNg annotations, don't know why Run as TestNg is not showing. On right Click> Run as > Run Configuration appears and when i click on Run configurations , no TestNg option appears in the list

Comment: do not post as an answer! otherwise it will be removed, edit your own post: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35520128/edit

Comment: I have added the code posted in an answer below (by the OP), as well as correcting various grammar issues and have attempted to make the text more readable with formatting.

Answer (score 2):

If the TestNG JARs are installed, you will be able to use all the annotations. But to run as TestNG, the plugin needs to be installed from Eclipse Market Place.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing testng plugin from eclipse market place..

Comment: @ sunder It's written Drag to Install in your running eclipse workspace . I have never installed TestNg plugin before.How this can be done . Please Help

Comment: Then you have to proceed to install plugin

Comment: Otherwise follow this step.     http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/install-testng/

Comment: I have added TestNG plugin but on running it is showing following errors-Unknown option: -serport
Usage:
[-d output-directory]
  default output directory to : test-output
[-testclass list of .class files or list of class names]
[-sourcedir a source directory]
[-annotations javadoc or JDK]
  Specifies the default annotation type to be used in suites when none is explicitly
  specified. This version of TestNG (15) supports both "javadoc" and "JDK" annotation types.
[-groups comma-separated list of group names to be run]
  works only with -testclass

Comment: Unknown option: -serport
Usage:
[-d output-directory]
  default output directory to : test-output
[-testclass list of .class files or list of class names]
[-sourcedir a source directory]
[-annotations javadoc or JDK]
  Specifies the default annotation type to be used in suites when none is explicitly
  specified. This version of TestNG (15) supports both "javadoc" and "JDK" annotation types.
[-groups comma-separated list of group names to be run]
  works only with -testclass........

Comment: Have you tried following.   this step. http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/install-testng

Comment: Is eclipse mars compatible with windows 8.1 64 bit .. I hope it's not compatibility issue

Comment: yes i have installed from this link toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/install-testng and now Run as > Run as TestNG option is coming .But with Error in Console which i have posted above and firefox driver cannot be launched

Comment: Try using eclipse Luna version

Comment: Now the Errors above in console are not appearing but java.lang.Null pointer exception is coming

Comment: eclipse.buildId=4.5.0.I20150603-2000
java.version=1.8.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ui
Warning
Sat Feb 20 00:32:02 PST 2016
The notification timed out Version: 1.0.0.v20150617-0732

org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ui.l10n.Logs$LogTraceException
 at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ui.l10n.Logs$LogTraceException.

Comment: Did you restart eclipse after installing plugin??

Comment: Eclipse luna version is better for maven and testng related projects

Comment: I have restarted again . On running as TestNG pop up came Unhandled event loop exception..Report this bug to Eclipse . Although there are no more Error logs now . Driver is also not launched

Comment: Have you used eclipse luna version?

Comment: It might be because you have low memory...reinstall eclipse again...Or.    Open the Configuration file in the eclipse directory forlder. for eg. C:\eclipse-jee-mars-SR2-win32\eclipse
just add -XX:MaxPermSize=256m command below the -vmargs line. Change value of

-XX:MaxPermSize as per your requirement. If your project is big you should use 512m or 1024m.